# Datastore query with limit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the RemoteAPI (Java) to go through a large dataset, ~90K entities, and perform some data migration.

```
int CHUNK_SIZE = 500;
int LIMIT = 900; 

QueryResultList<Entity> result = ds.prepare(entityQuery)
.asQueryResultList(
    FetchOptions.Builder
    .withPrefetchSize(CHUNK_SIZE)
    .limit(LIMIT)
    .chunkSize(CHUNK_SIZE)
).startCursor(cursor);
```

With the query `LIMIT` set to `900`the `result.size()` is the entire dataset, ~90K, instead of `900`. If I try a lower `LIMIT`, say `300`, the result size is the expected one (`300`).

What am I missing here? From the documentation I couldn't figure out why it produces the behaviour I'm describing here.

Comment: I'm maybe telling something stupid but have you tried changing the order of your options?  FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(LIMIT)
    .withPrefetchSize(CHUNK_SIZE)
    .chunkSize(CHUNK_SIZE)
).startCursor(cursor);

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see the `.limit` method to be in the Method Summary for the `FetchOptions.Builder` object (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions.Builder). Should be `.withLimit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these examples (http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultList)

I think that you should use `.withLimit(LIMIT)` instead of `.limit(LIMIT)` within the `.asQueryResultList` options

So I would restructure your code as follows:

```
FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder
    .withLimit(LIMIT)
    .withPrefetchSize(CHUNK_SIZE)
    .chunkSize(CHUNK_SIZE);

QueryResultList<Entity> result = ds.prepare(entityQuery)
    .asQueryResultList(options);
```

Then get cursor

```
result.getCursor();
```